# Length of stay vs Acute length of stay in a hospital

Tags: infection, diabetes, disease, hospital, icu-intensive-care-unit

I came across a term called `Acute length of stay` recently from a medical dataset hosted in Kaggle [here]
[1](https://www.kaggle.com/c/aws-challenge-2020-phase-1/overview)

While I understand that the usual `length of stay` is given by the formula `date of discharge - date of admission`.

But may I know what does `acute length of stay` mean? and how is it different from our regular length of stay calculation using the above formula?

Comment: Your first link doesn't go to anything related to your question.

Comment: Also, have you done any research on this? I found this easily. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5653133/